# Ionic 2: copying resources to android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-plugins

I added some images I want to add to android platform only. 
I've added the following lines under `<platform name="android">` in my `config.xml`:

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/ic_stat_push_android/drawable-hdpi.png" target="platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_push_android.png" />
```

However I can't seem to get it to copy. What do I need to run for the resource to be copied?

Comment: is this image used in app? usually all of the app assets are in `assets/imgs`.  If you only need it in one configuration perhaps you need to attach your copy to npm instead of config.xml.  Just a thought

Comment: @PhilipBrack this image is used for push notification. What do you mean by copy to npm?

Comment: I am used to adding to the npm scripts custom behavior.  that is what I mean.  Maybe [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this issue, this is the solution I ended up using.

1. create a file named `android_custom_resources.js`:

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var path = require('path');

   var sourceDir = 'resources/android/custom';
   var platformDir = 'platforms/android';
   var resourceDirs = [
   'res/drawable-ldpi',
   'res/drawable-mdpi',
   'res/drawable-mdpi-v11',
   'res/drawable-hdpi',
   'res/drawable-hdpi-v11',
   'res/drawable-xhdpi',
   'res/drawable-xhdpi-v11',
   'res/drawable-xxhdpi',
   'res/drawable-xxhdpi-v11',
   'res/drawable-xxxhdpi',
   'res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v11'
    ];

    module.exports = function(ctx) {
     if (ctx.opts.platforms.indexOf('android') < 0) {
       return;
     }

   var Q = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q');
   var deferred = Q.defer();
   var androidPlatformDir = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, platformDir);
   var customResourcesDir = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, sourceDir);

   function copy(src, dest) {
     var deferred = Q.defer();

     fs.stat(src, function(err, stats) {
       if (err || !stats.isFile()) {
         return deferred.reject(err);
       }

       fs.stat(path.dirname(dest), function(err, stats) {
         if (err || !stats.isDirectory()) {
           return deferred.reject(err);
         }

       var rs = fs.createReadStream(src);

       rs.on('error', function(err) {
         console.error(err.stack);
         deferred.reject(err);
       });

       var ws = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

       ws.on('error', function(err) {
         console.error(err.stack);
         deferred.reject(err);
       });

       ws.on('close', function() {
         deferred.resolve();
       });

       rs.pipe(ws);
     });
   });

   return deferred.promise;
   }

    fs.stat(customResourcesDir, function(err, stats) {
      if (err || !stats.isDirectory()) {
        return deferred.resolve();
     }

   fs.readdir(customResourcesDir, function(err, files) {
     var copies = [];
     for (var i in files) {
       var innerDir = path.join(customResourcesDir, files[i]);
       var innerFiles = fs.readdirSync(innerDir);
       for (var k in innerFiles){
         var innerFilePath = path.join(innerDir, innerFiles[k]);
         var innerDestPath = path.join(androidPlatformDir, 'res', files[i], innerFiles[k]);

         copies.push([innerFilePath, innerDestPath]);
       }
     }

     copies.map(function(args) {
       return copy.apply(copy, args);
     });

     Q.all(copies).then(function(r) {
       deferred.resolve();
     }, function(err) {
       console.error(err.stack);
       deferred.reject(err);
        });
      });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
   }
   ```
2. place it in a folder in your root project directory (in my case I called it `package_hooks` and reference it from your `config.xml`

   ```
   <hook src="package_hooks/android_custom_resources.js" type="after_prepare" />
   ```

this script assumes that inside your `<project root>/resources/android/custom` directory, files are placed in the folders named the same as the ones you expect them to be copied to. For example, if I have a file `<my project>/resources/android/custom/drawable-xxhdpi/myfile.png`, it will be copied to:
`<my project>/platforms/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/myfile.png`

It will surely break if you have files in the /custom directory itself, but otherwise it did the job for me and I hope it helps someone else looking for a temporary solution.